# Cant access method within method

Tags: methods, scope, vue.js

I am trying to access a method called filterCurrent() within the menuTags() method but vue is throwing an error that it doesn't recognise this.

I feel this has got to do with scope. Could anyone provide some insight as to why?

```
methods: {
      filterCurrent() {
        var self = this;
        // var results = this.results;
        var activeTags = this.currentTags.tags;
        //console.log(activeTags);
        this.results.filter(function (result) {
          // Reset current result to false;
          result.active = false;
          // Loop throigh current result tags
          result.tags.some(function (tag) {
            // Loop through activeTags

            activeTags.filter(function (activeTag) {
              // If one of the tags in the current result match any of the activeTag set it to active
              if (tag.indexOf(activeTag) != -1) {
                 //console.log(activeTags); 
                result.active = true;
                //console.log(activeTag);
              }
            })
          })
        }, this)
      },
      menuTags(label) {
        //this.currentTags.push(label.tags);
        //this.filterCurrent();
        let self = this;
        var passedTags = label.tags;
        console.log(passedTags);
        passedTags.filter(function(tag) {
            this.currentTags.push(tag);
        }, this)
        this.filterCurrent();
      }
    },
```

Comment: Could you please provide a link to jsfiddle or smth similar?

Comment: Sure. Give me a few minutes.

Comment: It looks like it calls the method OK: https://jsfiddle.net/nL28rey6/ but without seeing your data and template it's difficult to know what's going wrong.

Comment: Can you please provide the exact error.

Comment: I would like to note that you're using `some` and `filter` wrong: `some` returns true if its argument function returns true for any of the elements in the array. Similarly, `filter` returns a new array of elements that satisfy the predicate. In your question, you **never** use the return value of `some` and `filter`! You might as well use a regular `forEach`.

Comment: And another note: arrow functions maintain the `this` binding that was present when they are created. so you could have written `passedTags.forEach(tag => this.currentTags.push(tag))`.

Comment: Can you paste exact error message?